# Adding two of the same values to array instead of one - swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, uisearchbar

I am trying to make a search bar, where you can search for users names. The cell is showing two things - and image and a label.

The label is showing the users name and the image is showing the profile picture. The image needs the user userID to display his/her picture.

The `countryAndCode` contains the users userID called country, and the users name called code.

My problem is that it is adding the first user twice and I do not know why or how to change it.

Here is the relevant code, let me know if you would like to see more:

```
func startObersvingDB() {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("UserInformation").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

            let title = snapshot.value!["usersUID"] as? String
            let name = snapshot.value!["userName"] as? String
                self.tableData.append(title!)
                self.tableDataNames.append(name!)

            for i in 0..<self.tableData.count {

                print(self.tableDataNames.count)
                print(self.tableData.count)

                self.countryAndCode.append((self.tableData[i], code: self.tableDataNames[i]))//this shows error in XCode some times
                //if the above code doesn't compile then use the below code
                print("DONE")

                print(self.countryAndCode)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData() 
        })
    }
```

Comment: Independent to your question, please change `for i in 0...self.tableData.count - 1 {` with `for i in 0..<self.tableData.count  {`.

Comment: Using multiple arrays as data source is always bad and error-prone. Consider a custom class or struct.

Comment: index out of range issue ?

Comment: @vadian can you give me an example?

Comment: @NazmulHasan I get no error saying that - I get no errors at all, it just adds two users in the beginning, instead of just one

Comment: @shallowThought done - thanks! (did not help though, as you're stating)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343981/how-do-i-create-a-custom-struct-to-assign-the-contents-of-array-into-usable-vari) is an example, there are a few hundred more on Stackoverflow, custom structs / classes is very basic stuff in an object oriented language.